# Hyper-v 2012: Delete VM does not delete config files

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012

I have deleted a VM. In my folder for config files the xml is still there.
That can get messy if I add/remove a lot of VMs.

Is that by design? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The config files should get removed when you delete a VM through Hyper-V manager, and only leave virtual disk files (VHD and AVHD). Is this the only VM you have deleted to see if the behavior repeats?

Comment: I have played around and created and deleted. I had more xmls than Vms in my list.
So, I checked the name tag in the xml and deleted the xmls myself.

Comment: Are you creating VMs in their own separate folders?

Comment: Im not 100% sure, but I reinstalled server 2012 some while ago, pointing at the same location for the files. Maybe these VMs were created before reinstalling.
in that case, sorry for wasting your time.
Edit: The vhdx + config are on another partition and where never deleted when the host died.